# How to make the creation of a card dynamic?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

My Problem is that every  template created will be Added to the same Card like the image below shows it
And if i set the height rather than auto it will cut the card until the giving measurement.
is there anyone who can help me to make each template have it own card ?
[image: Image of the issue]

Card.Html

```
<div class="content"  >
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">     
     <div [fxFlex]="(100/gridColumns) + '%'" fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.sm="33%" >
        <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4 info" >
          <mat-card-content *ngFor="let item of templates" [innerHTML]="item.templatebody | safeTemplate"></mat-card-content>    <!-- named one way flow syntax property binding-->      
        </mat-card> 
         
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Card.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild,Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { EmailEditorComponent } from 'angular-email-editor';
import { SenderService } from "../sender.service";
import { TemplateCard } from "src/app/layouts/default/templates/template";
//this pipe is designed to make the HtmlRender Safe using SanitizerDOM
@Pipe({ name: "safeTemplate" })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: any) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cards',
  templateUrl: './cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cards.component.scss']
})
export class CardsComponent implements OnInit {
  public templates:TemplateCard[];
  public model: any;
  options = {
  };
  gridColumns = 3;
  toggleGridColumns() {
    this.gridColumns = this.gridColumns === 3 ? 4 : 3;
  }
  dangerousUrl='<input type="checkbox">';
  constructor(public http:SenderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.model=this.http.getEmail("http://localhost:3000/savetemplate").subscribe( data => {
      this.templates=data;
      console.log(this.templates); 
     },
     err => console.error(err),
     () => console.log('template completed')
     );}

  }
```

Comment: Just put your ngFor on the mat-card element instead

Comment: robbieAreBest!! Thanks for the answer it works:) i own you one bruh